# Pyodbc - print first 10 rows (python)

Tags: python, fetch, pyodbc

I'm trying to print the first 10 rows using pyodbc. I know how to get the first record by using the following:

```
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

I tried changing this to:

```
row = cursor.fetchten()
```

but this didn't work. Is there anything else I can do??

Comment: `fetchall` will return *all* the rows the cursor has, not just the first.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I don't do anything with pyodbc, so this could be complete gibberish, but couldn't you do `cursor.fetchall()[:10]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You insert:

```
row = cursor.fetchmany(10)
```

You can change the number in the parentheses to anything you want.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the documentation found [on this page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki), you've got two options for returning lists. You have the `fetchall()` method and the `fetchmany()` method. In either case, you're returned a list of rows to work with.

Regarding the `fetchall()` method and piggybacking off of what zondo said, the following works quickly and efficiently:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()[:10] # to get the first 10
rows = cursor.fetchall()[-10::1] # to get the last 10
```

Alternatively, you can loop over the rows as many times you need to get the results you need:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for idx in range(10): #[0, 1, ..., 9,] 
    print(rows[idx]) # to get the first 10
    print(rows[(len(ray)-idx)]) # to get the last 10
```

There is also the `fetchmany()` method in the same documentation, defined as follows: `cursor.fetchmany([size=cursor.arraysize]) --> list`

The brackets indicate optional parameters, so you do not need to include the size. But since you want 10, you will pass 10 into the size parameter. Example:

```
rows = cursor.fetchmany(size=10)
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```